# Attaching Order to User model using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have two models, a User and an Order (a user has many Orders)

The relationship is set as follows in my models:

**User Model**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

**Order Model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I am using the following code to attached the currently logged in User to a Order.

```
Auth::user()->orders()->attach($order_id);
```

I believe this is correct but I get this error when executing the code:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel v5.1 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `attach` method is meant for [many-to-many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships). To associate an order with a user in your scenario, you should be able to save the order model this way:

```
$order = App\Order::findOrFail($order_id);
Auth::user()->orders()->save($order);
```

Comment: You will need to first get the $order using `$order = App\Order::findOrFail($order_id);`

Comment: Correct. `$order` needs to be an instance of the order model. I wasn't sure if you had that already - thanks for pointing that out (I'll add it to my answer for reference).

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use associate() method and not attach(), because you are updating a belongsTo relationship.

Try this:

```
$order = App\Order::findOrFail($order_id);

$user->orders()->associate($order);

$user->save();
```

Comment: This just returns undefined method associate() instead